# udev rule script "xinput --list" differs in terminal versus log

Tags: linux, terminal, xorg, shell-script, udev

I'm trying to automate a Huion tablet calibration without much success.

I have this output from **`xinput --list`** in a normal terminal:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION PenTablet                           id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION PenTablet                           id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HUION PenTablet                           id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB USB Keyboard                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

udev log displays just this for the same command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] 
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ USB USB Keyboard id=13 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=16 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ Logitech USB Receiver id=14 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ HUION PenTablet id=18 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)] 
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Video Bus id=8 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Power Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Sleep Button id=10 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM id=11 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ USB USB Keyboard id=12 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=15 [slave keyboard (3)] 
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys id=17 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Note that the lines for `id=19` and `id=20` are missing.

I have:

**`/etc/udev/rules.d/huion.rules`:**

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="256c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="006e", SYMLINK+="davesusb", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/romulo/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/local/Huion"
```

**`/usr/local/Huion`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/romulo/.local/Huion &
```

**`~/.local/Huion`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3
DISPLAY=":0.0"
HOME=/home/romulo/
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY XAUTHORITY HOME

if (xrandr | grep "HDMI1 connected" > /dev/null)
then
    LENGTH=$(/usr/bin/xrandr | grep 'HDMI1 connected primary' | uniq |  awk '{x=$4; split(x,a,"+"); split(a[1],b,"x"); print b[1]}')
    WIDTH=$(/usr/bin/xrandr | grep 'HDMI1 connected primary' | uniq |  awk '{x=$4; split(x,a,"+"); split(a[1],b,"x"); print b[2]}')
    DEVICE=$(/usr/bin/xinput --list | grep HUION | uniq | awk 'NR==2 {x=$5; split(x,a,"="); print a[2]}')

    echo $(/usr/bin/xinput --list)

    CORRECTION=$((40000*$WIDTH/$LENGTH))
    echo "$CORRECTION"

    if (glxinfo | grep "Intel" > /dev/null)
    then
        xsetwacom set $DEVICE MapToOutput HDMI1
        echo "device $DEVICE restricted to HDMI-1"
        xinput set-prop $DEVICE "Evdev Axis Calibration" 0 40000 0 $CORRECTION
        echo "correction of proportion : 40000x$CORRECTION"        
    else
        echo "error :("
    fi
else
    echo "error :("
fi
```

The script does `xinput --list | grep HUION | uniq | awk 'NR==2 …'`
in an attempt to capture the `id` of the second HUION device (i.e., `19`)
and so it fails because that information is not present. 
How can I overcome this problem?

**update 1**

**Root** through **`sudo su`** gives me the same **`xinput --list`** as normal user but any attempt to calibrate did not have effect. I will need to switch to my user in udev shell script invocation? Not much elegant... :(

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I need the relevant ids of the device, in the question the script try to obtain the second HUION device that is id 19, it isn't visible through udev so I can't realize calibration.

Comment: While this is clearly not the source of your problem, it is highly recommended that you put all references to shell variables into quotes (e.g., `"$DEVICE"` and `"$CORRECTION"`) unless you have a good reason not to and you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be related but users show my user logged 2 times

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that xinput list is refreshed after udev rules processing and no timeout in background process can overcome it. The solution is in triggering your script via inotify. Original solution and needed script sources can be found at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1626055#p1626055.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to trigger the udev rule with `ACTION=="bind"` instead of `ACTION=="add"` (Because I saw with `udevadm monitor` that it was last action when I connected a mouse)